# How to redirect already answered incoming call using pjsip?

Tags: c#, asterisk, pjsip, freepbx

I use pjsip.dll for creating softphone app. Answering and dialing works fine.
Now, I need to redirect already answered incoming call to another sip-user (for example, from number 101 to 104). How to do that? I cannot find function in pjsip sdk docs.
I have a C# app (softphone with sipek sdk wrapper), PBX, Asterisk.

Comment: For those, who need solution: For Sipek SDK: ```CallManager.onUserTransfer(globalSessionId, redirectNumber_edit.Text); ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library should have SIP transfer option.

If it have no, freepbx have transfer code like *2(pause 0.1sec), 100(pause 0.1),#, Hangup. Just use DTMF and send that sequence.

Comment: Yes, I already found this func in library. For Sipek SDK:

CallManager.onUserTransfer(globalSessionId, redirectNumber_edit.Text);